# How should I handle the browser freezing due to a large amount of data?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have created a web page where data can be loaded into a google chart for displaying it visually. Everything works well when the data set is small, but as soon as it approaches 10,000 points or more, the browser starts to freeze.

Is there any way to stop the freezing other than lowering the amount of data displayed or cutting it off after a certain limit is reached?

Comment: Can you process that data before rendering it? For example, I'm sure not all 10,000 points are individually visible at a time. Thus, you could average some of the points so only a portion of them are rendered - *while still maintaining a proper representation of the data*. My guess is that the freezing is happening during rendering, not just having those points in memory.

Comment: The term you are looking for is paging. 
There is no way a user is going to want to see all >10K rows at once in one page.
This would:
(1) Increase the execution time of the script.
(2) Probably crash the browser trying to display so much of data.
For effective execution of the script use pagination and/or put limits on your queries.

Comment: I'm not talking about paging. Just averaging points. It's difficult to determine what data is being rendered (since OP didn't mention). But assume you're rendering a path from point A to B, represented by a curve made up of 10,000 points. Instead of rendering points A1, A2, A3, ...An, you could render a single line between A1 and An - or a line that represents the average of those points in between.

Comment: The data being shown is engine data. Things like RPM, fuel rate, oil temperature, etc. I am interested in the averaging idea you mentioned, but I am concerned that it might remove outliers from showing when they are probably what matters most.

Answer (score 0):

Can you scale the data before being worked with?

For example, if you have 5-10k visitors each day and you want to have chart that shows growth of visits in month, divide all numbers with 1000 and than process them. Than write below (or where ever) that scale is x1000.

I'm guessing is not as simple as this, but believe that can be done on these principles.